# How can I set up dynamic routing such that the url/route selected is part of the decision making progress for the component/module to be loaded?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular13

Using Angular 13, I'm trying to set up something like this:

```
src/app
│  app.module.ts
│  app-routing.module.ts
│
└─feature-root-module
   │  feature-root.module.ts
   └──layouts
   │   │  MainLayoutComponent.ts
   │   │  SecondaryLayoutComponent.ts
   │
   └──other-sub-modules
```

Here, feature-root-module is entirely lazy loaded, and the following routes are set in app-routing-module. Both routes lead to the same module.:

```js
{
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./feature-root-module/feature-root.module").then(
        (module) => module.FeatureRootModule
      ),
    canLoad: [MainAuthGuard],
  },
  {
    path: 'secondary',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./feature-root-module/feature-root.module").then(
        (module) => module.FeatureRootModule
      ),
    canLoad: [SecondaryAuthGuard],
  },
```

`feature-root-module` is set up with a factory method for resolving routes.

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainLayoutComponent, SecondaryLayoutComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ROUTES,
      useFactory: FeatureRootRouteFactory,
      deps: [Router],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class FeatureRootModule {}

export function FeatureRootRouteFactory(router: Router): Routes {
  let routes: Routes = [];

  // The following lines are where I'm struggling
  const routeSections = window.location.pathname.url
    .split("/")
    .filter((x) => !!x);

  const layout =
    routeSections[0] === "main"
      ? MainLayoutComponent
      : SecondaryLayoutComponent;
  // End of section that I need to figure out.

  routes = [
    {
      path: "",
      component: layout,
      children: [
        {
          path: "some-sub-module",
          loadChildren: () =>
            import("./some-sub-module/some-sub.module").then(
              (module) => module.SomeSubModule
            ),
          canActivate: [SomeSubModuleGuard],
        },
      ],
    };
  return routes;
}
```

What I want to do is this: If the user visits `/main/some-sub-module`, then the MainLayoutComponent should be used with the routerOutlet within it showing `some-sub-module`s contents.

However, if the user visits `/secondary/some-sub-module`, the the SecondaryLayoutComponent should be used with the routerOutlet within it showing `some-sub-module`s contents.

I can do this by using windows.location.pathname, but that doesn't seem very 'Angular'. I've tried using ActivatedRoute as well as Router, but neither of them have the route data as it hasn't been populated at this point. What Angular way can I use to do something like this.

In the larger scheme of things, I want this as a pattern as the FeatureRootModule has dozens of fairly complex child modules and different combinations of routes may show different variations of the child modules. Instead of creating clones of FeatureRootModule, I'm trying to figure out if I can use the url to decide which modules/components to return.